# Generic SQL for update / insert

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I'm writing a DB layer which talks to MS SQL Server, MySQL & Oracle. I need an operation which can update an existing row if it contains certain data, otherwise insert a new row; All in one SQL operation.

Essentially I need to save over existing data if it exists, or add it if it doesn't

Conceptually this is the same as upsert except it only needs to work on a single table. I'm trying to make sure I don't need to delete then insert as this has a performance impact.

Is there generic SQL to do this or do I need vendor specific solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: from a generic standpoint, you may be better off using delete + insert approach.  Assuming you're using indexed columns, you should be ok.  However, as podiluska comments, purely generic SQL is a myth once you get deeper into the weeds.

Answer (score 3):

You need vendor specific SQL as MySQL (unlike MS and Oracle) doesn't support `MERGE`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

I suspect that sooner rather than later, you're going to need a vendor specific implementation of your DB layer - SQL portability is pretty much a myth as soon as you do anything even slightly advanced.

Comment: Yes, we already do vendor specific stuff but I do prefer to keep it simple & generic + merge seems designed for operating on two tables not one... I haven't managed to get it working yet but even if I do it feels like a hack.

Comment: @user999091 - your understanding of MERGE is confused.  MERGE executes an upsert on a *single* table.  However it needs a source of data; this would commonly be another real table but it could just as easily be a virtual table.  At this point you run into more vendor differences: how you would handle this in Oracle is different from how you would handle it in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is going to be vendor specific. For SQL Server, you can accomplish this using the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, use Merge Statement. But keep in mind that if your Insert part has some condition involve, then it cannot be used. In which case you need to write your own way for accomplishing this. And in  your case it has to be since you are involving MySQL which does not have a Merge Statement.

Why are you not using an ORM layer (like Entity Framework) for this purpose?

Just some pseudo code(in C#)

```
public int SaveTask(tblTaskActivity task, bool isInsert)
        {
            int result = 0;

            using (var tmsEntities = new TMSEntities())
            {

                if (isInsert) //for insert
                {
                    tmsEntities.AddTotblTaskActivities(task);
                    result =  tmsEntities.SaveChanges();
                }
                else //for update
                {
                    var taskActivity = tmsEntities.tblTaskActivities.Where(i => i.TaskID == task.TaskID).FirstOrDefault();
                    taskActivity.Priority = task.Priority;
                    taskActivity.ActualTime = task.ActualTime;
                    result = tmsEntities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Given how many words you wrote for this answer would it really have been so much more effort to type *you* and *your* rather than *u* and *ur*?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you have something similar to merge:

insert ... on duplicate key update ...

[MySQL Reference - Insert on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)